# App/Deep Linking is not working from browser Android

Tags: android, react-native

Deep Linking not working in my react native app(Android) when I clicked link from browser. It's working from ADB.

**AndroidManifest.xml:**

```
<activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:launchMode="singleTop"
            android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:label="Cashare" android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

            <data android:scheme="https"
                  android:host="casharetesting.badrit.com" android:pathPrefix="/"/>

        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Clicking on this [url](https://casharetesting.badrit.com/cashare/group_invitations/KUHNpepNeAfJc2G-nJQo) in browser is not working however it's working from adb in terminal:

```
adb shell am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -d " https://casharetesting.badrit.com/cashare/group_invitations/KUHNpepNeAfJc2G-nJQo"
```

Comment: I have the exact same issue, adb command executing successfully, but manually opening the link in chrome doesn't work. Did you manage to solve this problem back then? if so, how did you do so?

Comment: @hazem any update on this?

Comment: any update on this?